# Windows Mobile security policies?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

Is there an equivalent to Windows' group policies on Windows Mobile?

My goal is to prevent users from being able to change the date or time on a Windows mobile device and instead ideally allow an application to change it instead.

Answer (score 2):

The only tool that may allow to manage such settings is SCMDM (System Center Mobile Device Management: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Center_Mobile_Device_Manager).

But you can use a blacklist (http://community.intermec.com/t5/Device-Management/Tips-collection-thread/m-p/2941#M375)

```
REGEDIT4
;Enable blacklist of applications that should not run
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Security\Policies\Shell]
"DisallowRun"=dword:1
;Add entries to blacklist of applications that should not run
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\DisallowRun]
"1"="clock.exe"
```

You can also disallow access to certain control panel settings using ReDirect="" key

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\ControlPanel\Clock]
"Redirect"=""
```

But all this can not replace a good locked down kisok mode application.

I have written several posts about kiosk mode: http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2012/05/29/windows-mobile-kiosk-mode-series-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of one. That does not mean it doesn't exist, though.

Our solution here has been to set the device's time every time a database connection to our server is made by forcing all applications to use a global "get open connection" method that first calls `SELECT GetDate();` on our SQL Server and sets the Device's date before returning the open connection to the calling method.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an equivalent to Windows' group policies on Windows Mobile?

Windows Mobile is pretty much dead except for the medical community. OT: platform certification is expensive and time consuming (its the FDA equivalent of FIPS 140), so many medical devices still use the older Windows CE core. It could be popular elsewhere, such as Automotive (I don't work with the industry, so I don't know).

Windows Mobile devices do take group policies, so there is no need for an equivalent. Information is still available online and in MSDN. For example, [Managing MDM Devices](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd261728.aspx) and [Configuring Device Group Policy Settings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd252805.aspx).

Jeff